# Is it possible to make the OS reroute from C:/path to D:/path?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, filesystems, remapping

I lack space on a drive. I cannot simply split the data I store between two drives or the applications using it will fail.

Is there a way to split the data and have the OS (Windows 10) take care of automatically accessing a different drive for specific folders without having the applications noticing any difference.

For example, let's say I have two folders, `C:/folderA/` and `C:/folderB/`, and I do not have room for both on `C:/`.

Is there a way to move `C:/folderB/` to another drive at `D:/folderB/` and tell the OS to automatically access this other drive when asked for `C:/folderB/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Create a [NTFS junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) from `C:/folderB/` to `D:/folderB/`; the VFS will transparently map accesses from the first to the second.

Comment: It looks like what I am looking for ! Thanks ! If I may add, by looking up junctions, I found out about [symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9042542/what-is-the-difference-between-ntfs-junction-points-and-symbolic-links) as well which might be another way to do the same trick. I'm letting this here if it helps somebody else.